# static html served by Node express won't show on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, node.js, express, responsive-design

My first time to try some responsive design on desktop and iPhone at the same time.

I have successfully connected my iPhone(5s) with my Mac OSX (Yosemite) on my Mac's IP address. After creating a basic Node Express server, I confirmed that the "Hello World" response shows both on my desktop Chrome and iPhone Safari.

However, when I tried to serve static html files with app.use(), I can only see it on desktop Chrome. My iPhone Safari stopped to display anything. Could you help me identify the issue, please? Thank you very much!

Here's my file structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DxCj.png)
Here's my code:
server index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/public')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // this commented part won't work either:
  // res.status(200).sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/public/index.html'));
  res.status(200).send('I\'m from server')
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('iphone dev app listening on port 8080');
});
```

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>iPhone</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my index.js on my client side:

```
(function() {
  let app = document.getElementById('app');
  app.innerHTML = "I'm from js";
  console.log(app);
})();
```

Comment: Do you have any any ability to see errors in the browser on the iPhone side of things?  Can you run it in the iPhone simulator and see errors there?  We'd like to see what the iPhone browser is unhappy about.

Comment: FYI, I don't see how `/../client/public` in  your `express.static()` combines with `src="./assets/js/index.js"` to yield the location of index.js in your server file system.  That's a mystery to me.  Where is the server JS file located that has the `app.use()` in it (I want to know what `__dirname` is)?  Where is the intended client-side `index.js` file in your file system?  Please tell me the whole path of both of those.

Comment: @jfriend00 the __dirname in path.join(__dirname, 'somethingelse') is the path to the current folder, which is where index.html lives. This piece of code works very well on desktop Chrome. I don't think this path thing is the issue. Client-side index.js lives in: "dev on iphone"/client/public/assets/js/index.js, css file lives in "dev on iphone"/client/public/assets/css/style.css, index.html lives in "dev on iphone"/client/public/index.html

Comment: You can connect your phone to your mac and see the phone's safari's console on your desktop's safari. I'm sure there is some hint there.